# HttpClient: Count cannot be less than zero. Parameter name: count

Tags: c#

I use HttpClient to perform REST calls to remote server:

```
using (var response = httpClient.PostAsync(Url, content).Result)
{
// code
}
```

It works fine, but sometimes it returns strange error:

> 2014-07-28 12:04:40,098 (268795336) [114] ERROR -
>   System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --->
>   System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending
>   the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection
>   was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. --->
>   System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Count cannot be less than zero.
>   Parameter name: count
>   at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)

What could be the cause of the problem?

Comment: What's content and Url?

Comment: Are you doing more than one request at once (i.e. multithreaded usage)? This wouldn't be the first time there's been a race condition in HttpClient's internals...

Comment: It looks like this error is happening on the server, not the client side.  Can you post the server-side code?

Comment: @Liath: Url does not matter.I can't reproduce it a week, sometimes it takes two days. Restarting application solve the problem for a while. I can't post server-side code, I call external service.I don't think the problem is on server side, I can make requests from local instance without problems.

Comment: to @Cameron: I use HttpClient in server application, and yes, it can perform many request at once

Comment: @Vasil: Try putting a global lock around any HttpClient method calls and see if that fixes it. If it does, it's a race condition (and it should be possible to write a unit test that creates a lot of threads over and over that all do requests at once until the race presents itself again).

Answer (score 1):

I guess the occasional problem might be caused by a deadlock. When we are using async methods, it is better to use `await` rather than `Task.Result` for the above reason. Do take a look at this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) which discuss about best practices in asynchronous programming.

Comment: But wouldn't that result in a deadlock rather than an (obscure) exception?

Comment: There could be exceptions thrown because of deadlock but those exceptions will be wrapped in System.AggregrateException when you synchronously block on a Task using Task.Wait or Task.Result.

Comment: I receive the error immediately. Does not look like deadlock.